# How to correctly make a datastore query in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Trying to get entities from my google cloud datastore, filtered by a key name. Not sure what am I doing wrong here in my code.

I create my datastore

```
const ds = new Datastore({
  projectId: "my-project",
  keyFilename: "./servicekey.json",
  namespace: "client-dummy",
});
```

Then create a key for filtering

```
  const _key = ds.key({
    namespace: "client-dummy",
    path: ["transactions", data.id],
  });
```

create my query by supplying the namespace, kind and key based filter.

```
const query = ds
    .createQuery("client-dummy", "transactions")
    .filter("__key__", _key);
```

And finally run the query

```
const result = await ds.runQuery(query);
```

But results are always empty

```
[ [], { moreResults: 'NO_MORE_RESULTS', endCursor: 'CgA=' } ]
```

I have tried running same queries on the UI and get results. I don't know what's wrong in the code. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that such object exist? What is `data.id`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Because I made the same query on the datastore UI and get expected results. data.id is correct. I printed it on console log.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the same code on my side, and was having the same issue. To be able to replicate I have mocked the `data.id` as `const data = {id: 1}`, then created an entity to match the use case and indeed had the same behavior.

After playing little while with it, I noticed in UI (Datastore in GCP)  in “Edit entity” that **Key literal** is `Key(transactions, '1')` which means that this ‘1’ is a String.

Just adding toString() method helped. So key creation looks like this:

```
const _key = ds.key({
    namespace: "client-dummy",
    path: ["transactions", data.id.toString()]
  });
```